# regex to match character sequence and only one type of symbol

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex for matching sequences of characters. i want it to only match if one type of separator (a space, "/" or "-") is used, not a combination of all.

`^(([1-9]|1[0-3]|A|J|Q|K|a|j|q|k)(C|D|H|S|c|d|h|s))( |\-|\/)(([1-9]|1[0-3]|A|J|Q|K|a|j|q|k)(C|D|H|S|c|d|h|s))( |\-|\/)(([1-9]|1[0-3]|A|J|Q|K|a|j|q|k)(C|D|H|S|c|d|h|s))( |\-|\/)(([1-9]|1[0-3]|A|J|Q|K|a|j|q|k)(C|D|H|S|c|d|h|s))( |\-|\/)(([1-9]|1[0-3]|A|J|Q|K|a|j|q|k)(C|D|H|S|c|d|h|s))`

for example i want it to match:

```
as/3d/0S/Td/13C
```

but not:

```
As/3d-QS/Ad/13C
```

or:

```
As-2d QS/Td 13C
```

Comment: Is the use of regex mandatory?

Comment: Sounds like [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) are exactly what you're looking for

Comment: First cant match, you can't have 0 only, and no T

Comment: In the first occurrence of your separator, use `((-(?!.*[ /]))| (?!.*[-/))|/(?!.*[- ])))` to forbid any further occurrences of the other separators. Then use `[-/ ]` for each next separator.

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all, but the first of occurance of this `( |-|/)` to this `\4`. So you backreferencing what it was matched first and expect that everywhere else. ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/0fgOWA/8))

Answer (score 3):

You can first, simplify the regex a lot, it would be more readable

- `(C|D|H|S|c|d|h|s)` -> `[CDHScdhs]`
- `([1-9]|1[0-3]|A|J|Q|K|a|j|q|k)` -> `([1-9]|1[0-3]|[AJQKajqk])`
- `( |\-|\/)` -> `[ \/-]`

Then you may use *backreference* to assure that the same separator is used, it represents the index of the group to use, after simplification it's the group `2` in my regex  [take a look](https://regex101.com/r/ndn3N2/4)

Also as all part are the same you could simplify in

```
^([1-9]|1[0-3]|[AJQKajqk])[CDHScdhs]([ \/-])(([1-9]|1[0-3]|[AJQKajqk])[CDHScdhs]\2?)+$
```

---

But setting the `re.IGNORECASE` flag, you can remove uppercase letters

```
^([1-9]|1[0-3]|[ajqk])[cdhs]([ \/-])(([1-9]|1[0-3]|[ajqk])[cdhs]\2?)+$
```

[`==> FINAL REGEX`](https://regex101.com/r/ndn3N2/3)

Answer (score 0):

A solution without regex seems much cleaner:

```
def check_string(the_string):
    # return True if exactly two of ' ', '-', '/' do not appear in the_string
    counters = [the_string.count(' '), the_string.count('/'), the_string.count('-')]
    return counters.count(0) == 2
```